# How can I fix "Not Allowed" error on Add All to Wishlist?

Tags: wishlist

If I click "add all to wishlist", I get a blank white page with the error "Not Allowed" and nothing else on screen, I am using Magento CE 1.9.1.1,

I have tried removing my theme and I have made sure all my folders are set to 755 and files to 644 (suphp) but I cant think of how to fix.

Could it be a corrupt core file, if so, which or where should I start looking? Or maybe an issue in htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed: My host Clook looked into this issue for me (I reported error as: "In firefox and chrome I get a blank page with "Not Allowed" printed, on IE I get a 403 page."). 
Their answer: The issue was a modsec rule: "Generic SQL inline command protection" and it was the URI of those particular requests that was causing this to be flagged. Rule has been switched off.